# Query on Python tkinter bind event

Tags: python, tkinter

Friends, I'm trying to make hover effect in python(3.5.2) on a button, I use the below code.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200+400+400")
myBtn = Button(root, text="TEST")
myBtn.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

myBtn.bind("<Enter>", lambda event, h=myBtn: h.configure(bg="red"))
myBtn.bind("<Leave>", lambda event, h=myBtn: h.configure(bg="yellow"))

root.mainloop()
```

It works strange.
 
when I hover mouse over the button, first time nothing happens
and when I leave, it gives yellow (satisfying the second event binded).

I couldn't find where I made mistake. could some one point me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `<Enter>` binding you just need to set `activebackground` instead of the plain `background` (`bg` is a synonym of `background`).

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200+400+400")
myBtn = tk.Button(root, text="TEST")
myBtn.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

myBtn.bind("<Enter>", lambda event, h=myBtn: h.configure(activebackground="red"))
myBtn.bind("<Leave>", lambda event, h=myBtn: h.configure(bg="yellow"))

root.mainloop()
```

I changed the `import` statement from the messy "star" import, which imports 135 Tkinter names into your namespace. This requires a little more typing, but it makes the code easier to read & maintain because it makes it obvious which names come from Tkinter.